# sudo apt-get update problem

Tags: 12.04, updates, sudo

I have a problem with `sudo apt-get update` that I can't seem to fix and It's causing problems with alot of installations I want to do. I run Ubuntu 12.04.

```
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise InRelease
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates InRelease                             
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports InRelease                           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security InRelease                            
Get:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [2,979 B]                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                        
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                             
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise Release.gpg                                   
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates Release.gpg                           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports Release.gpg                         
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security Release.gpg                          
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages/DiffIndex      
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free TranslationIndex             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise Release                                       
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates Release                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports Release                             
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security Release                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/main TranslationIndex                         
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                   
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/restricted TranslationIndex                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/universe TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                 
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages               
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/main TranslationIndex               
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex         
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex         
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex           
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US             
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/main TranslationIndex                
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex          
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex          
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/universe TranslationIndex            
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US                
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/main Sources                                  
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/restricted Sources                            
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/universe Sources                              
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/multiverse Sources                            
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/main amd64 Packages                           
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/restricted amd64 Packages                     
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/universe amd64 Packages                       
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                     
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/main i386 Packages                            
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/restricted i386 Packages                      
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/universe i386 Packages                        
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise/multiverse i386 Packages                      
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/main Sources                          
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/restricted Sources                    
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/universe Sources                      
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/multiverse Sources                    
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/main amd64 Packages                   
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages             
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages               
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages             
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/main i386 Packages                    
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages              
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/universe i386 Packages                
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages              
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/main Sources                        
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/restricted Sources                  
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/universe Sources                    
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/multiverse Sources                  
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/main amd64 Packages                 
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages           
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages             
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages           
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/main i386 Packages                  
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages            
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/universe i386 Packages              
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages            
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/main Sources                         
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/restricted Sources                   
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/universe Sources                     
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/multiverse Sources                   
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/main amd64 Packages                  
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages            
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/universe amd64 Packages              
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages            
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/main i386 Packages                   
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/restricted i386 Packages             
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/universe i386 Packages               
404  Not Found Err http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages             
404  Not Found Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/main Translation-en_US                        
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/main Translation-en                           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/multiverse Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/multiverse Translation-en                     
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/restricted Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/restricted Translation-en                     
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/universe Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise/universe Translation-en                       
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/main Translation-en_US                
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/main Translation-en                   
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US          
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en             
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_US          
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/restricted Translation-en             
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/universe Translation-en_US            
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-updates/universe Translation-en               
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/main Translation-en_US              
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/main Translation-en                 
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US        
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/restricted Translation-en_US        
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/restricted Translation-en           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/universe Translation-en_US          
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-backports/universe Translation-en             
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/main Translation-en_US               
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/main Translation-en                  
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_US         
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/multiverse Translation-en            
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/restricted Translation-en_US         
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/restricted Translation-en            
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/universe Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ftp.availo.se precise-security/universe Translation-en              
Fetched 2,979 B in 9s (328 B/s)                                                
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following    signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I would appreciate a fix to this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: you can go to software-sources and disable those ppa's

Comment: you may need to add  '/ubuntu' to the 'http://ftp.availo.se' entries (use 'deb http://ftp.availo.se/ubuntu ' on the entries for that mirror)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, there is a problem with the particular Ubuntu mirror you have selected as your software source.

Maybe you should try changing it. Go to Ubuntu Software center, and from the "Edit" menu choose "Software sources". You will see a window like the one beneath; choose another "Download from" location and try to run the updates again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

open the  `/etc/apt/sources.list` by your favorite text viewer then you can do one of the following:

Either

Correct your software source list by adding /ubuntu to the entries that make the problem for you.

OR

You can just remove those ppa's that make this problem if you dont want to use anymore